# How to call the Microsoft Graph API from an Azure Durable Function?

Tags: azure-durable-functions

I planned on writing an Azure Durable Function that calls multiple activities. One of the activities would call the Microsoft Graph API.

I found a [sample of a non-durable Azure Function that calls the Graph API](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-azurefunction-csharp), but I don't know how to apply the code from the sample to the Azure Durable Function.

The current issue I have is that in the sample, the classes and HTTP triggers are non-static and declare two variables `_tokenValidationService` and `_graphClientService`, but a durable function has only static classes and methods, which do not let me do that.

```cs
// ...
namespace GraphSampleFunctions
{
    public class GetMyNewestMessage
    {
        private readonly ITokenValidationService _tokenValidationService;
        private readonly IGraphClientService _graphClientService;
// ...
```

Unlike the the non-durable function for example, the logger is also not declared in the class, but retrieved from within the task by the `executionContext.GetLogger()` method.

```cs
// ...
[Function("SecurityGroupCreate_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SecurityGroupCreate_HttpStart");
// ...
```

I assume I have to somehow get the Graph client into the executionContext object?

I would appreciate if I could get some advice, how one would call the Graph API from a an Azure Durable Function.

Comment: Not sure what version or execution mode you are using but you can have non-static functions. I have HTTP trigger functions which are non-static and use dependency injection via their constructor.

Comment: @phil Would you provide a sample project with a single graph call from an activity, please? (Isolated)